# Creating jars from a class and using in in other programs

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a newbie in Java.

I have a java file A which I want to call in another java program B.

I want to create jar for the A and use it in B by creating the objects and calling the methods for A.

What type of jar is to be created and how can I add it to the library. Please help how to do it in Eclipse.

Also, how to import the jar in B.

Answer (score 3):

You can go to File->Export->jar-File
name your jar-file (you do not need a runnable jar)

after that you can open your other project B 
right-click -> properties-> java build path

select libraries and click on add external jars

choose your exported jar-file. Click ok
and it is imported to your actual project B

now you can use classes and methods of this jar-File

Answer (score 1):

1. First create a project in eclipse with class A ([Creating project in Eclipse](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-jdk-ide-tutorials/253-beginners-eclipse-tutorial-how-run-first-java-application-eclipse.html))
2. Export this project as jar ([Exporting jar in Eclipse](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm))
3. Create another project with class B and set class path of for exported jar ([Setting class path in Eclipse](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29))

Now you can use object of A in B.

```
 import com.A;
 public class B{
    public static void main(String[] args){
           A a=new A();
           //.......
}
 }
```

Comment: Ok. got it.
But how to import the jar.
Lyk we use import java.util.StringTokenize for using StringTokenize class in the program.

Comment: import class A in class B.

Comment: I have created A.jar for A.java file. How to import it in B?

Comment: @Pooja3101 Since you are using eclipse, after you write the class name press `ctrl+1` ,look at the first suggestion. BTW, have you added that  created jar to your class path ?

Comment: OK. I did it. Its working fine. Can u explain how to do it in Linux. I mean where to add jar if I want to use A.jar in B.java